# Some general method to find limit, accumulation and isolated points of a set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a hard time finding limit, accumulation and isolated points of sets so I was wondering if there is some general way to approach such problems.

So for example consider a simple subset of the reals $$S= \{1+\frac{1}{n+1} | n\in \mathbb{N} \}$$
Can you explain how I would find the limit, accumulation and isolated points in this set?

The way I would do it is this, for limit points I would just find the limit of $1+\frac{1}{n+1}$ which is 1, for isolated points I would consider open sets around each point and realized that not every open set contains points of $S$ therefore every point is an isolated point, now for accumulation points I have no idea how how to find them.

Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A \subseteq X$. Then, $x \in X$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if $\forall r > 0, B(x, r) \cap (A\backslash \{x\}) \ne \emptyset$. Also note that **accumulation point** is also called **limit point**.

So here, if you can deduce that every point in $S$ is an isolated point, then they cannot be accumulation point (It is important to note that we exclude the point itself from the intersection). Other than that, it is always good to check whether the limit is accumulation point or not since limit is one of the best candidates for being an accumulation point.

Here, I assume our bigger set is $\mathbb{R}$. Then, $\forall r > 0$, we can check the intersection $B(1, r) \cap (S\backslash \{1\})$. But note that since we are in $\mathbb{R}$, we have $B(1,r) = (1-r, 1+r)$. Here, by using $\mathbb{Q}$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$, one can show that we can find an element of the form $1+\frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$ in the interval $(1,1+r)$, for any $r > 0$ (because it is equivalent to find a rational number of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ in the interval $(0,r)$, but this is easy to show once you know what dense means). Then, the intersection will not be empty for any such $r > 0$, and thus by definition, $1 \in \text{Acc}(S)$.

Now, I'm leaving to you to check whether there are other accumulation points in $\mathbb{R}\backslash S$ or not.